# Distinct Difference on Match and Where clauses

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two queries – one restricts on the MATCH and the other does it on the WHERE. They are all based on northwind dataset.

1. `MATCH (n:Employee)-[:SOLD]->(:Order{shipName:"North/South"}) RETURN (n)`

   - Returns 3 nodes Andrew, Janet and Janet (note the duplicate for Janet)
2. `MATCH (n:Employee) WHERE (n)-[:SOLD]->(:Order{shipName:"North/South"}) RETURN n`

   - Returns 2 results Andrew and Janet

Finally I have a third query that features both:

3. `MATCH (n:Employee)-[:SOLD]->(o:Order{shipName:"North/South"}) WHERE (n)-[:SOLD]->(:Order{shipName:"North/South"}) RETURN n`

   - This returns 3 nodes as well, bit surprised by the query order – the match is applied after the where?

The questions is how come they 1 & 2 don’t return the same result? Also as per http://neo4j.com/blog/introducing-new-cypher-query-optimizer/ does moving the matches to the WHERE clause not change the results?

Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: How your model looks like?

Comment: @MicTech http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sql-to-cypher/#_northwind_example_model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect your confusion is because MATCH() is about patterns and WHERE is about a single logical yes/no. Also, I'm thinking Janet has two orders in the system while Andrew has one order which affects the results returned by MATCH() when a WHERE isn't used.

Model 1 returns a join of the "Employee" and "Order" labeled nodes, and since Janet has two orders she's reported twice while Andrew is reported once.

Model 2 would be phrased as "Does this employee have *any* orders in the system?" This is because the WHERE phrase returns a single true/false for each employee node. That's why you're seeing Andrew and Janet once instead of Janet twice.

Model 3 is a combination of models 1 and 2 and it returns a "union" of the two sets of results.